# install ojdbc7 maven command on windows

Tags: maven, variables, installation, environment, ojdbc

How to configure maven and ojdbc7 on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download apache maven 3.6.3
   https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi
2. Download ojdbc7.jar
   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/ojdbc7/12.1.0.2
3. Configure environment system variables

3.1 Create variable          MAVEN_HOME
value             C:\apache-maven-3.6.3-bin\apache-maven-3.6.3 (Directory of apache maven unpacked and uncompressed until file readme.txt )

3.2 Add value in path       %MAVEN_HOME%\bin

4. NSTALL JDBC by MVN on location folder jar by cmd
   mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc7.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc7 -Dversion=12.1.0.2 -Dpackaging=jar

Now you can use your project on Netbeans, Intellij Idea o Eclipse before all download source, dependencies, and source that you project needed.

Good Luck

Comment: I am not sure whether it is legal to download ojdbc7 from the given address.